# Git Changes not staged for commit and Untracked files

Tags: git, github

I want to push project on my repository.

and i run this code git commit -m "first commit"

but give me this error

[image: ss]

Comment: I suggest you to read a little bit more about git concepts before continuing your work. Atlassian offer a very good introduction to git concepts and commands : https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/what-is-version-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahmet

You need to add your files to the stage area, the fastest way is to add everything to your commit with `git commit -a` then write your initial message.

[Git boot](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is another good way to learn git

Answer (score 0):

Have you added these files using `git add some_filepath` ?
If you begin and don't confortable with all git commandds, I highly recommend you to train [here](https://try.github.io).